# Ajax.ActionLink failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

Right now I'm learning about MVC's implementation of Ajax and I'm having trouble getting it to work correctly. Here's what I have:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click here to get a title", "Yo",
    new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "alert(\"YES!\")", OnFailure = "alert(\"WHY?!\")" })
```

And here are the two controller methods:

```
    public PartialViewResult GetThatTitle()
    {
        var titular = new TitleDataEntity { };
        titular.TitleName = "Inception!";
        titular.PublishDate = DateTime.Now;
        titular.Id = 2;

        return PartialView("_testView", titular);
    }

    public JsonResult Yo()
    {
        var titular = new TitleDataEntity { };
        titular.TitleName = "Inception!";
        titular.PublishDate = DateTime.Now;
        titular.Id = 2;
        if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(titular);
        }
        return Json(titular);
    }
```

When I call the function "Yo", the browser gives me the "WHY?!" alert box. But when I call GetThatTitle, it gives me the success alert. Why is it failing when I try and return a Json result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow GET requests like this when returning JSON which are disabled by default:

```
return Json(titular, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Also I would strongly recommend you using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/). It shows all AJAX requests in its console and you see the requests and responses. If you have used it you would have seen the following:

> InvalidOperationException: This
>   request has been blocked because
>   sensitive information could be
>   disclosed to third party web sites
>   when this is used in a GET request. To
>   allow GET requests, set
>   JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.]

which would have put you on the right track of course.

Comment: Man, I feel like an idiot. Thanks for the help and the prompt reply. You rock.